# Get request not working after modifying htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, get, request

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product-detail.php?asin=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^product product.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^product/page/([0-9]+)$ product.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Why Does the `.htaccess` above affect my GET request?

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $Product_page = $_GET['page'] ;
}
else {
    $Product_page = 1;
}
```

I'm getting the pages with using page parsed on the URL like `product.php?page=`. But when I access the GET request after changing the URL to `/product/page/6` it doesn't get the second page. The first page is working because the default is 1.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^product product.php [L,NC]
> ```

I'm surprised this isn't resulting in a rewrite-loop? (But this is possibly dependent on the rest of your config. For instance, do you have `MultiViews` enabled?)

This catches any request that simply *starts* `/product` and rewrites to `/product.php`. So, `/product/page/6` is rewritten to `/product.php` and the page number is lost. Incidentally, a request for `/product` would also be caught by the first `RewriteRule`, rewriting the request to `product-detail.php?asin=product`?! Also, if you do have `MultiViews` enabled then this would also conflict.

You could do something like the following instead:

```
Options -MutliViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product-detail.php?asin=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product(?:/page/([0-9]+))?$ product.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

This combines both rules and makes the `/page/<n>` part of the URL optional. Which would result in a rewrite to `product.php?page=` - *see note below*.

Are you sure you need the `NC` flag on the 2nd `RewriteRule`? This potentially creates "duplicate context" unless you have canonical tags in place. (I've removed it on the first, as you are already checking for upper/lowercase directly in the regex.)

> ```
> if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
>     $Product_page = $_GET['page'] ;
> }
> else {
>     $Product_page = 1;
> }
> ```

You are seemingly trusting the value of the `page` URL param. As noted above, this could legitimately be empty, so should default to `1` for any *invalid* value as well - not just when it is not present at all.